# Prototype cell reuse while radio button select

Tags: ios, objective-c

While select radio button on cell1 at the time other cell radio button automatically selected i need to set one radio button at one cell i hve many cell with 5 or more radio button 
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with what are you doing in 'didSelectrowAtIndexPath' ?

Comment: check this code https://www.dropbox.com/s/j02yotvevxfp821/jsonTableView%203.zip?dl=0

Comment: I am sure that this issue occurs when you scroll , You have to keep tract and update data source when you select - deselect radio button, in cell for row check that you have to show selected or not for given cell

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to maintain list/item of selected item from radio button. 
In didSelectRowAt from tableview you can perform following steps If you are checking with string else you can do it from option id base.

```
selectedItem.removeAllObjects() // AS radio button is kept only one selected at a time.
selectedItem.add(currentCell.answerLabel?.text)
self.tableView?.reloadData()
```

In cellForRowAt you can perform following steps

```
if (isItemSelected(optionText: answerOption) == true) {
   answerCell.answerOption?.image = UIImage(named: "radio_on")
 }
 else {
   answerCell.answerOption?.image = UIImage(named: "radio_off")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your radio button state and set it on every cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

Or you can implement the function called

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {}
```

In your tablewViewCell subclass. In that method, set your radio button to its normal state.